# RequireJs: How to define extra dependencies for 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, requirejs

Basically I want to be able to load some module first before other. For example, I want bootstrap to load first before backbone. Can I declare dependencies like so?

```
shim: {
    'backbone': {deps: ['bootstrap']}
}
```

Comment: The code in Backbone does not depend on bootstrap being loaded before Backbone is. So why do you want to do this?

Comment: Boostrap modify jQuery on load and I got a bug where Backbone.$ sometime does not contain Bootstrap (but window.$ does), I suspect that this is because Backbone is loaded before Bootstrap. Later I fix it simply by modifying Backbone.$ in my main app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the way to do it (in the `require.config({ ...` block of course.) It is also recommended to add an `exports` key and set it to `Backbone`. This will allow you to use Backbone inside a `require` or `define` block, as though it were a real AMD module:

```
define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
  // Backbone here is the function parameter instead of the global reference
});
```

Read more [here](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim). In fact they even reference Backbone as their example!

Comment: A quick look at source code reveal that Backbone is AMD compliant and have the following dependencies by default: underscore, jquery, exports. That's why I was wondering if defining extra dependencies via require.config is the way to go. Though as you pointed out, require.js do include backbone as their example so I think it might work out.

Comment: Huh. This might mean that the requirejs docs are outdated, that is,  backbone has been updated to be AMD compliant since the docs were written. In this case, perhaps I would send the requirejs team an email asking for the proper procedure.