# Add Custom JS and CSS Files to Custom Yeoman Generator

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman

I'm trying to build a custom yeoman generator and I'm basing if off of the webapp generator from yeoman.  I'm need to know how to add certain js and css files if bootstrap is not selected.  These files are currently being stored at the same level as my index.html file along with main.css.

I've tested the generator and everything works just fine, I just can't figure out how to add certain files or exclude them if bootstrap is present.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Please ask a question before a down vote.  This is the first time I've messed with a custom generator.

Below is my index.js file:

```
'use strict';

var join = require('path').join;
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
var chalk = require('chalk');

module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
  constructor: function () {
    yeoman.generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);

    // setup the test-framework property, Gruntfile template will need this
    this.option('test-framework', {
      desc: 'Test framework to be invoked',
      type: String,
      defaults: 'mocha'
    });
    this.testFramework = this.options['test-framework'];

    this.option('coffee', {
      desc: 'Use CoffeeScript',
      type: Boolean,
      defaults: false
    });
    this.coffee = this.options.coffee;

    this.pkg = require('../package.json');
  },

  askFor: function () {
    var done = this.async();

    // welcome message
    if (!this.options['skip-welcome-message']) {
      this.log(require('yosay')());
      this.log(chalk.magenta(
        'Out of the box I include HTML5 Boilerplate, jQuery, and a ' +
        'Gruntfile.js to build your app.'
      ));
    }

    var prompts = [{
      type: 'checkbox',
      name: 'features',
      message: 'What more would you like?',
      choices: [{
        name: 'Bootstrap',
        value: 'includeBootstrap',
        checked: true
      },{
        name: 'Sass',
        value: 'includeSass',
        checked: false
      },{
        name: 'Modernizr',
        value: 'includeModernizr',
        checked: false
      }]
    }, {
      when: function (answers) {
        return answers && answers.feature &&
          answers.features.indexOf('includeSass') !== -1;
      },
      type: 'confirm',
      name: 'libsass',
      value: 'includeLibSass',
      message: 'Would you like to use libsass? Read up more at \n' +
        chalk.green('https://github.com/andrew/node-sass#node-sass'),
      default: false
    }];

    this.prompt(prompts, function (answers) {
      var features = answers.features;

      function hasFeature(feat) {
        return features && features.indexOf(feat) !== -1;
      }

      this.includeSass = hasFeature('includeSass');
      this.includeBootstrap = hasFeature('includeBootstrap');
      this.includeModernizr = hasFeature('includeModernizr');

      this.includeLibSass = answers.libsass;
      this.includeRubySass = !answers.libsass;

      done();
    }.bind(this));
  },

  gruntfile: function () {
    this.template('Gruntfile.js');
  },

  packageJSON: function () {
    this.template('_package.json', 'package.json');
  },

  git: function () {
    this.template('gitignore', '.gitignore');
    this.copy('gitattributes', '.gitattributes');
  },

  bower: function () {
    var bower = {
      name: this._.slugify(this.appname),
      private: true,
      dependencies: {}
    };

    if (this.includeBootstrap) {
      var bs = 'bootstrap' + (this.includeSass ? '-sass-official' : '');
      bower.dependencies[bs] = "~3.2.0";
    } else {
      bower.dependencies.jquery = "~1.11.1";
    }

    if (this.includeModernizr) {
      bower.dependencies.modernizr = "~2.8.2";
    }

    this.write('bower.json', JSON.stringify(bower, null, 2));
  },

  jshint: function () {
    this.copy('jshintrc', '.jshintrc');
  },

  editorConfig: function () {
    this.copy('editorconfig', '.editorconfig');
  },

  mainStylesheet: function () {
    var css = 'main.' + (this.includeSass ? 's' : '') + 'css';
    this.template(css, 'app/styles/' + css);
    // Add imod-grid.css
    var imod = 'imod-grid.' + 'css';
    this.template(imod, 'app/styles/' + imod);
  },

  writeIndex: function () {
    this.indexFile = this.engine(
      this.readFileAsString(join(this.sourceRoot(), 'index.html')),
      this
    );

    // wire Bootstrap plugins
    if (this.includeBootstrap && !this.includeSass) {
      var bs = 'bower_components/bootstrap/js/';

      this.indexFile = this.appendFiles({
        html: this.indexFile,
        fileType: 'js',
        optimizedPath: 'scripts/plugins.js',
        sourceFileList: [
          bs + 'affix.js',
          bs + 'alert.js',
          bs + 'dropdown.js',
          bs + 'tooltip.js',
          bs + 'modal.js',
          bs + 'transition.js',
          bs + 'button.js',
          bs + 'popover.js',
          bs + 'carousel.js',
          bs + 'scrollspy.js',
          bs + 'collapse.js',
          bs + 'tab.js'
        ],
        searchPath: '.'
      });
    }

    this.indexFile = this.appendFiles({
      html: this.indexFile,
      fileType: 'js',
      optimizedPath: 'scripts/main.js',
      sourceFileList: ['scripts/main.js'],
      searchPath: ['app', '.tmp']
    });
  },

  app: function () {
    this.directory('app');
    this.mkdir('app/scripts');
    this.mkdir('app/styles');
    this.mkdir('app/images');
    this.write('app/index.html', this.indexFile);

    if (this.coffee) {
      this.write(
        'app/scripts/main.coffee',
        'console.log "\'Allo from CoffeeScript!"'
      );
    }
    else {
      this.write('app/scripts/main.js', 'console.log(\'\\\'Allo \\\'Allo!\');');
    }
  },

  install: function () {
    this.on('end', function () {
      this.invoke(this.options['test-framework'], {
        options: {
          'skip-message': this.options['skip-install-message'],
          'skip-install': this.options['skip-install'],
          'coffee': this.options.coffee
        }
      });

      if (!this.options['skip-install']) {
        this.installDependencies({
          skipMessage: this.options['skip-install-message'],
          skipInstall: this.options['skip-install']
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RequireJs: How to define extra dependencies for 3rd party library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696465/requirejs-how-to-define-extra-dependencies-for-3rd-party-library)

Comment: @Paul: I’m not sure I understand how this is a duplicate. This is talking about Yeoman, Bower, and a few other things; but RequireJS is not one of those things, and the question you suggest this is a duplicate of is *all about* RequireJS.